# Combined horizontal and vertical rotation angle?

Tags: trigonometry

I am a programmer and I am working on a game tool used in a tank-combat simulator. I usually post my questions on StackOverflow, but this one is Math-only, so I'm guessing this site suits it better.

---

I am trying to calculate the *"Effective Armour Thickness"* of a metal plate being used as sloped armor on a tank.

For a perfectly horizontal and lined shot to the front of the tank, the angle is simply the same of the slope. But if the tank is rotated a little on it's axis, the angle is a compound of the horizontal and vertical rotations.

Basically, I am trying to calculate the same as is calculated in [this page's](http://www.panzerworld.net/armourcalculator) *"Combined angle calculator"*, but I don't know the formula being used.

While searching for a solution, I have found [this article](http://www.mathsrevision.net/alevel/pages.php?page=11), but it doesn't seems to be it that I want.

What is the correct formula to achieve the same results that the *"Combined angle calculator"* outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the formula after looking a little deeper in the page's source-code.

For anyone interested:

`combinedAngle = (90 - (acos(cos((90 - Angle_A) * PI / 180) * cos((90 - Angle_B) * PI / 180)) / PI * 180))`